ingesting data from ADLS directory containing .txt, .txt.parquet and .parquet files with databricks autoloader
I have a location in ADLS and need to ingest data from said location into Unity Catalog.
This directory in ADLS has a mixture of .txt, .txt.parquet and .parquet.
I am using autoloader and parquet option to ingest this data.


CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE Example_raw
TBLPROPERTIES ("quality" = "bronze") 
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files("/mnt/Example", "parquet");



But the presence of .txt and txt.parquet files is causing the ingestion to fail.
Can autoloader handle multiple file types in a ingestion?
Thanks

Answer to your specific question:
The autoloader can only work with one
file format at a time.
Possible workaround:
To ingest multiple file formats into the same table using autoloader, you could try using a UNION ALL with a corresponding glob filter (pathGlobFilter option) for each file format.  I haven't tested the code below, but hopefully the concept conveys:
CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE Example_raw
TBLPROPERTIES ("quality" = "bronze") 
AS
SELECT *
  FROM cloud_files(
    "/mnt/Example",
    "parquet",
    map("pathGlobFilter", "*.parquet"))
  UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM cloud_files(
    "/mnt/Example",
    "text",
    map("pathGlobFilter", "*.txt"))
;

Files matching the filter must match the defined format. So, *.txt.parquet files must actually be Parquet files or the ingestion will fail.
See AutoLoader syntax and pathGlobFilter under File Format Options for additional details.

Sorry if this is obvious, but how will you handle the .txt files, since here youre only filtering for the .parquet files?

@Brett - I revised my answer.  Hope this helps.
